# loading image from google in Ionic returns error 403

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to load image from google user content, by adding the url with the photo from google to the src atribute.

```
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPs4YaP3-Ok_MctA-97vU3fr3iaf-R0LFEgz4qe=s1600-w400"
```

In browser it works well, but in my ionic app it throws me error 403.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally I have managed to solve it by editing the network_security_config.xml file and adding the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://lh3.googleusercontent.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
     <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: It does not help for me :(

Comment: it helped me with release apk version of app but same issue in debug apk. Also I used "googleusercontent.com" only this part inside network security config file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but I noticed the forbidden status is generated when you send the header `referer: http://localhost/` if you remove or change the value of this header, for example with a valid www website, you obtain the image without errors.

```
curl 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/{{img_url}}' \
  -H 'authority: lh3.googleusercontent.com' \
  -H 'accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost/' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: image' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: no-cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; Build/TPP2.220218.008; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: {{ionic package}}' \
  --compressed
```

I dont't know how to force the webview to do that, but I'm afraid embedding the image inside an `<img>` tag is not enough and you need to do the request with javascript, set headers manually, and get the image in a javascript var as base64 (me too)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, you can add referrerPolicy="no-referrer" to your image tag:

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPs4YaP3-Ok_MctA-97vU3fr3iaf-R0LFEgz4qe=s1600-w400" referrerPolicy="no-referrer" />
```